# Значение таймера из таблицы

Tags: c#

Нужно взять дату из колонки `dt_send_daytime`. Т.е 1:1:4:0 каждую неделю,каждый понедельник, в час, 4 минут так должно работать. Можно так сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где тут поставить дату?

```js
  foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) {


    MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();


    string dt_str = row["shedule_dt_send_daytime"].ToString();

    string[] dt_str_tmp = dt_str.Split(':');

    switch (row["time_name_ru"].ToString().ToUpper()) {
      case "ЧАС":
        Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[2] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[3]); //мм:сс
        break;

      case "НЕДЕЛЯ":
        Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[0] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[1]); //дд:чч
        break;

      case "ДЕНЬ":
        Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[1] + ":" + dt_str_tmp[2]); //чч:мм
        break;

      case "МИНУТ":
        Console.WriteLine(dt_str_tmp[3]); //сс
        break;



    }

       // вот тут надо что-то вставить

    myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(row["shedule_dt_send_daytime"]);

    myTimer.alg = Convert.ToString(row["meta_cod"]);
    // myTimer.Dt_Begin = Convert.ToDateTime(row["shedule_dt_beg"]);
    // myTimer.Dt_Period_End = row["shedule_dt_period_end"];




    myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(dt_str_tmp);

    myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
    myTimer.AutoReset = true;
    myTimer.Enabled = true;




  }
```

Comment: В "час и 4 минуты" или в "час" работать 4-минуты?

Comment: Это время интервала: каждый понедельник,  в час  и 4 минуты 0 секунд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно!

1. Когда происходит запуск программы/функции ты определяешь день недели сегодня.

   ```
    int today = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
   ```

Подробности: [Практическое руководство. Извлечение дня недели из конкретной даты](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb762911(v=vs.110).aspx)

2. Определив день, проходишь по всем строкам таблицы и проверяешь соответствует ли 1-ый символ в колонке `dt_send_daytime` номеру полученного тобою дня недели. Если да, то запускаешь таймер с нужными параметрами.

   ```
   if (today == dt_str_tmp[0])
     {
        // создаешь таймер
     }
   ```

**UPDATE**: Вставлять после `switch`

Comment: вот это я сделать не могу) Поможете?

Comment: @propro17: Чего именно вы не можете?

Comment: @propro17 да у тебя же уже все есть. Осталось получить сегодняшний день недели

Comment: @MaximK Покажите пожалуйста . Просто незнаю как делать (соответсвует ли 1-ый символ ).обновил вопрос –

Comment: да все просто...  `строковая_переменна[номер_символа]`

Comment: этот код относятся к `switch`?

Comment: сделал комментарий у тебя в вопросе. `switch { ... }  if (today...`

Comment: `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39996/discussion-between-maximk-and-propro17).

Comment: @MaximK добрый день) вы решили?